# Deleted fields and access Rights from res.partner model in openerp?

Tags: python, odoo

I have problem with res.partner. Unfortunately fields and access Rights deleted from res.partner model When I try to creating the field through user interface.

Please see the attached screenshot,

[image: res.partner fields]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by restart the server with `-u all` option